# Relocated virtualenv ( which was relocatable ) doesn't point to correct python

Tags: python, virtualenv

**Virtualenv creation and activating**

```
vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs$ virtualenv venv_test 
New python executable in /home/vikram/test_dirs/venv_test/bin/python Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done. 

vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs$ source venv_test/bin/activate
(venv_test) vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs$ which python  
/home/vikram/test_dirs/venv_test/bin/python
(venv_test) vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs$ deactivate
```

**Making virtualenv relocatable:**

```
vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs$ virtualenv --relocatable venv_test
Making script /home/vikram/test_dirs/venv_test/bin/pip2 relative
Making script /home/vikram/test_dirs/venv_test/bin/python-config relative
Making script /home/vikram/test_dirs/venv_test/bin/pip2.7 relative
Making script /home/vikram/test_dirs/venv_test/bin/pip relative
Making script /home/vikram/test_dirs/venv_test/bin/easy_install-2.7 relative
Making script /home/vikram/test_dirs/venv_test/bin/easy_install relative
Making script /home/vikram/test_dirs/venv_test/bin/wheel relative

vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs$ source venv_test/bin/activate
(venv_test) vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs$ which python
/home/vikram/test_dirs/venv_test/bin/python
(venv_test) vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs$ deactivate
```

**Moving virtualenv :**

```
vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs$ mv venv_test test_dir2/
vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs$ cd test_dir2/
vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs/test_dir2$ ls
venv_test
vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs/test_dir2$ source venv_test/bin/activate
```

**Incorrect python location**

```
(venv_test) vikram@vikram-XPS-15-9530:~/test_dirs/test_dir2$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

After following above steps looks like virtualenv is not properly moved everything. Please let me know if something wrong. I was expecting "which python" will show path to python from same virtualenv.

Comment: I've noticed that virtualenv --relocatable does not change the activate script for some reason. this feature is probably broken